# MSCRM 2011 Create a new user record using a dialog process

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Goal: Create a dialog process that allows the end user to create a NEW user record (by entering their user name, first name, last name), and assign them to a "pre-made" security role.

Is this possible? It should be an extremely easy thing to do.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

Create process >> Category: Dialog >> Add "Create Record" step" >>
THEN when I go to select the User entity it is not in the drop down list. Even my custom entities appear but not the User entity.

What's up Microsoft? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you can create new users other than through the normal new user process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a User with the standard step of a Dialog/Workflow.

However if your CRM environment is On-Premise you can try to write a Custom Workflow Activity to create the user and use it inside the dialog process.

You can refer to these two links:

[MSDN - Sample: Create an On-Premises User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602984.aspx)

[MSDN - Create a Custom Workflow Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx)